# Нужна помощь по установке шрифтов

Tags: css, шрифты

Вот здесь (http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse) пишет, что чтобы установить шрифт, то всего лишь нужно сделать так:

```css
    @font-face {
    font-family: Pompadur; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    src: url(fonts/pompadur.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    }
```

Хотя когда я так делаю, то у меня почему-то так и не работает то все, не понимаю, почему?

Также я замечал замечать в других шаблонах, что там есть еще одна строка:

```css
src: url(../fonts/avantgardegothicc-bold.otf?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
url(../fonts/avantgardegothicc-bold.otf) format("OpenType"),
url(../fonts/avantgardegothicc-bold.html) format("truetype");
```

Я без понятия, что оно значит, но половину моих шрифтов заработала, а других, которые с расширением .ttf- нет.

У меня 2 вопроса, как сделать так, что бы работали все у меня шрифти. И почему там на сайте указано, что чтобы установить шрифт, нужно всего лишь вписать такой короткий код, хотя на самом деле это не так, потому что надо вон те все форматы настраивать еще

Comment: а сам шрифт вы скачали и положили в относительный путь, на который ссылаетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка или в пути к файлу шрифта ,или в его имени(расширении).Стоит помнить что `../` означает степень уровня вложения ссылаемого файла т.е. что элемент в родительском катологе.

Comment: Нет, я там все правильно прописал. Вот шрифты с расширением otf работают, а с ttf почему-то нет

Answer (score 0):

Прописывать все эти форматы в css нет необходимости. Просто воспользуйтесь font-face генератором и подключите готовый шрифт. Можно онлайн (http://transfonter.org) ИЛИ через npm-модуль.